# Hybris 6.7 server startup issue on upgrading from 6.3

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, sap-commerce-cloud, sapjvm

While doing an prod deployment and starting the server with 6.7 after upgrading from 6.3 we receive the following error in the console

> INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 | SEVERE: LifecycleException 
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 | java.lang.VerifyError: (class: de/hybris/bootstrap/loader/metrics/ClassLoaderMetricRegistry, method: incrementEventCounter, signature: (Lde/hybris/bootstrap/loader/metrics/ClassLoaderMetricEvent;)V, offset: 21) invokedynamic bytecode is not supported in this class file version
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.PlatformInPlaceClassLoader.(PlatformInPlaceClassLoader.java:32)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappLoader$HybrisWebappClassLoader$1.call(HybrisWebappLoader.java:127)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappLoader$HybrisWebappClassLoader$1.call(HybrisWebappLoader.java:1)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappLoader$HybrisWebappClassLoader.invokeWithLock(HybrisWebappLoader.java:190)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappLoader$HybrisWebappClassLoader.getPlatfromInPlaceClassLoader(HybrisWebappLoader.java:109)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappLoader$HybrisWebappClassLoader.(HybrisWebappLoader.java:104)
>   INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2019/08/13 00:46:11.308 |     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Evnironment details:-
Java : SAP JVM 8
Hybris : 6.7 patch 13

Tried reverting back to Java 8 instead of SAP_JVM 8 but still the same issue. Works fine in other environments with both java configs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue was due to one property in local.properties which is

> tomcat.generaloptions=-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xms12g -Xmx12g -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xloggc:${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/java_gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_init_tomcat.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}" -Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true

This property includes -XX:-UseSplitVerifier which was causing the issue. -*XX:-UseSplitVerifier* is deprecated as of Java 8.